# Select Single Field in two Column (Mysql) for Not Ordered Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not very good in mysql queries. That's why asking the question again.

We are using **Mysql** Database and we have Single tables that is **employee_transaction**.

**employee_transaction table**

```
id |  employee_id | date            | transaction_type
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 2015-01-01      | 1
2  | 1            | 2015-12-31      | 0 
3  | 1            | 2015-07-01      | 1
4  | 2            | 2014-02-01      | 1 
5  | 1            | 2016-04-01      | 1
6  | 2            | 2014-11-30      | 0
7  | 1            | 2016-08-01      | 1
8  | 1            | 2016-10-31      | 0
```

And so on.

To get the proper Result, the following Conditions need to be satisfied :-

- First transaction_type of any employee is always 1.
- Any Employee cannot have Consecutive transaction_type=0.
- The result of two consecutive transaction_type are below.These
  results is for one Employee

  1. **If both Transaction_type=1.** Then start_date=first transaction date,
     end_date= second transaction date-1 and transaction_type=1.
  2. **If first Transaction_type=1 and next transaction_type=0.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date, end_date= second transaction date
     and transaction_type=1.
  3. **If first Transaction_type=0 and next transaction_type=1.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date+1, end_date= second transaction
     date-1 and transaction_type=0.
  4. **If No transaction is found after transaction_type=0.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date+1, end_date= Null and
     transaction_type=0.

We need the Query of following output from the **employee_transaction** table.

```
 employee_id |  start_date     | end_date       | transaction_type
------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 2015-01-01      | 2015-06-30     | 1
 1            | 2015-07-01      | 2015-12-31     | 1 
 1            | 2016-01-01      | 2016-03-31     | 0
 1            | 2016-04-01      | 2016-07-31     | 1
 1            | 2016-08-01      | 2016-10-31     | 1
 1            | 2016-11-01      | (Null)         | 0 
 2            | 2014-02-01      | 2014-11-30     | 1
```

Thanks in advance.

If you have any concerns/clarification required, revert me.